# How to close a MessageBox after several seconds

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

I have a Windows Forms application VS2010 C# which displays a MessageBox with an OK button.

How can I make it so that, if the user walks away, the message box automatically closes after a timeout of, say, 5 seconds?

Comment: Take a look at this (Windows Phone, but should be the same): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674122/how-to-make-a-messagebox-disappear-after-3-seconds

Comment: You can create the Form as a `MessageBox`

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Try the following approach:

```
AutoClosingMessageBox.Show("Text", "Caption", 1000);
```

Where the `AutoClosingMessageBox` class implemented as following:

```
public class AutoClosingMessageBox {
    System.Threading.Timer _timeoutTimer;
    string _caption;
    AutoClosingMessageBox(string text, string caption, int timeout) {
        _caption = caption;
        _timeoutTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(OnTimerElapsed,
            null, timeout, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
        using(_timeoutTimer)
            MessageBox.Show(text, caption);
    }
    public static void Show(string text, string caption, int timeout) {
        new AutoClosingMessageBox(text, caption, timeout);
    }
    void OnTimerElapsed(object state) {
        IntPtr mbWnd = FindWindow("#32770", _caption); // lpClassName is #32770 for MessageBox
        if(mbWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
            SendMessage(mbWnd, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        _timeoutTimer.Dispose();
    }
    const int WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
}
```

**Update:**
If you want to get the return value of the underlying MessageBox when user selects something before the timeout you can use the following version of this code:

```
var userResult = AutoClosingMessageBox.Show("Yes or No?", "Caption", 1000, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
if(userResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes) { 
    // do something
}
...
public class AutoClosingMessageBox {
    System.Threading.Timer _timeoutTimer;
    string _caption;
    DialogResult _result;
    DialogResult _timerResult;
    AutoClosingMessageBox(string text, string caption, int timeout, MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.OK, DialogResult timerResult = DialogResult.None) {
        _caption = caption;
        _timeoutTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(OnTimerElapsed,
            null, timeout, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
        _timerResult = timerResult;
        using(_timeoutTimer)
            _result = MessageBox.Show(text, caption, buttons);
    }
    public static DialogResult Show(string text, string caption, int timeout, MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.OK, DialogResult timerResult = DialogResult.None) {
        return new AutoClosingMessageBox(text, caption, timeout, buttons, timerResult)._result;
    }
    void OnTimerElapsed(object state) {
        IntPtr mbWnd = FindWindow("#32770", _caption); // lpClassName is #32770 for MessageBox
        if(mbWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
            SendMessage(mbWnd, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        _timeoutTimer.Dispose();
        _result = _timerResult;
    }
    const int WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
}
```

**Yet another Update**

I have checked the @Jack's case with `YesNo` buttons and discovered that the approach with sending the `WM_CLOSE` message does not work at all.
I will provide a *fix* in the context of the separate [AutoclosingMessageBox](https://github.com/DmitryGaravsky/AutoClosingMessageBox) library. This library contains redesigned approach and, I believe, can be useful to someone.
It also available via [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoClosingMessageBox):

```
Install-Package AutoClosingMessageBox
```

**Release Notes (v1.0.0.2):**

- New `Show(IWin32Owner)` API to support most popular scenarios (in the
  context of [#1](https://github.com/DmitryGaravsky/AutoClosingMessageBox/issues/1) );
- New `AutoClosingMessageBox.Factory()` API to provide full control on MessageBox showing;

**Release Notes (v1.0.0.3):**

- New Count-Down feature (in the context of [#4](https://github.com/DmitryGaravsky/AutoClosingMessageBox/issues/4));
- NET.6 migration;

Comment: Better use System.Threading.Timer or System.Timers.Timer (like @Jens answer) ? SendMessage vs PostMessage ?

Comment: @Kiquenet I believe there are no significant differences in this specific situation.

Comment: @DmitryG Is it possible to let me know how to do the same but with splash screen or a picture instead of message box?

Comment: @DmitryG I'm also asking how to display the countdown in a label?

Comment: @user1460166 about countdown...just change the timer settings to iterate timer-callbacks multiple times and add some code to send the `WM_SETTEXT` message into the window...

Comment: I see you pass null for lpClassName, isn't there any special classname for the MessageBox window? If so, one could use it to make the chance of closing some other window that has the same caption smaller

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis Thanks, it can make a sense... In this case you can use `#32770` value as a class name

Comment: Would be even nicer, if one could get the return value of the underlying `MessageBox` if the user selects something before the timeout. Also, isn't there some risk of closing the wrong window with the same caption?

Comment: I would recommend two small changes to this code: 1. Make the constructor private so you force people to call the Show method. 2. Make the class implement IDisposable and then wrap the return statement in a using statement; that way the timer doesn't go off after the user has already pressed the button.

Comment: @SoaperGEM Please, check my code - the constructor is private. Regarding IDisposable - the last variant of implementation is proffered, and it is not intended to be used with IDisposable rather then with DialogResult. Moreover, there are no scenarios which can produce timer's leak.

Comment: Whoops, my mistake on the constructor. It seems I copy/pasted a modified version which had it public. But there is indeed a chance for the timer to leak as you have it above... in fact I just watched it leak while debugging. I set a breakpoint in OnTimerElapsed, then called AutoClosingMessageBox.Show() with a 5-second timeout. As quickly as I could I pressed the "OK" button, which closes the dialog. But 5 seconds later it still hit my breakpoint.

Comment: Ok, this make a sense. I've added a "fix"  by wrapping a `MessageBox.Show` with `using(_timeoutTimer)`. Thanks for collaboration!

Comment: It does not work for me if buttons are `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.YesNo`

Comment: @Jack Sorry for late reply, I have checked the case with `YesNo` buttons - you are absolutely correct - it does not work. I will provide a fix in the context the separate [AutoclosingMessageBox](https://github.com/DmitryGaravsky/AutoClosingMessageBox) library. The contains the redesigned approach and, I believe can be useful. Thanks!

Comment: To use [AutoClosingMessageBox](https://github.com/DmitryGaravsky/AutoClosingMessageBox) library by @DmitryG with ```showCountDown=True``` options on Visual Basic projects ```Application.EnableVisualStyles()``` and ```Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)``` are required

Answer (score 46):

A solution that works in WinForms:

```
var w = new Form() { Size = new Size(0, 0) };
Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
    .ContinueWith((t) => w.Close(), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

MessageBox.Show(w, message, caption);
```

Based on the effect that closing the form that owns the message box will close the box as well.

Windows Forms controls have a requirement that they must be accessed on the same thread that created them. Using `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` will ensure that, assuming that the example code above is executed on the UI thread, or an user-created thread. The example will not work correctly if the code is executed on a thread from a thread pool (e.g. a timer callback) or a task pool (e.g. on a task created with `TaskFactory.StartNew` or `Task.Run` with default parameters).

Comment: What's version .NET ? What's it TaskScheduler ?

Comment: @Kiquenet .NET 4.0 and up. `Task` and `TaskScheduler` are from namespace `System.Threading.Tasks` in mscorlib.dll so no additional assembly references are needed.

Comment: Great solution! One addition... this worked well in a Winforms app, AFTER adding BringToFront for the new form, right after creating it.  Otherwise, the dialog boxes sometimes showed *behind* the  current active form, i.e., did not appear to the user.
            var w = new Form() { Size = new Size(0, 0) };
            w.BringToFront();

Comment: @Developer63 I could not reproduce your experience. Even when calling `w.SentToBack()` right before `MessageBox.Show()`, the dialog box still showed on top of the main form. Tested on .NET 4.5 and 4.7.1.

Comment: This solution could be nice, but it is only available from .NET 4.5 and up, not 4.0 (because of Task.Delay)
see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717047/system-threading-task-does-not-contain-definition

Comment: @KwentRell You are correct. `Task` in .NET 4.0 does not have `Delay` yet.

Comment: How to default to Yes? Now the result is the default which is No.

Answer (score 19):

## AppActivate!

If you don't mind muddying your references a bit, you can include `Microsoft.Visualbasic,` and use this very short way.

Display the MessageBox

```
    (new System.Threading.Thread(CloseIt)).Start();
    MessageBox.Show("HI");
```

CloseIt Function:

```
public void CloseIt()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.AppActivate( 
         System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
    System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(" ");
}
```

Now go wash your hands!

Answer (score 11):

You could try this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.Dll")]
static extern int PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 msg, int wParam, int lParam);

private const UInt32 WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;

public void ShowAutoClosingMessageBox(string message, string caption)
{
    var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000) { AutoReset = false };
    timer.Elapsed += delegate
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, caption);
        if (hWnd.ToInt32() != 0) PostMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
    };
    timer.Enabled = true;
    MessageBox.Show(message, caption);
}
```

Comment: Better use System.Threading.Timer or System.Timers.Timer (like @DmitryG answer) ? SendMessage vs PostMessage ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376619/what-is-the-difference-between-send-message-and-post-message-and-how-these-relat and maybe also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411116/equivalent-of-postmessage-in-c-sharp-to-synchronize-with-the-main-thread-with-mv on the difference between SendMessage and PostMessage

Comment: `timer` was getting garbage collected before the elapsed event in some cases, so it can be made into a class member

Answer (score 11):

The System.Windows.MessageBox.Show() method has an overload which takes an owner Window as the first parameter. If we create an invisible owner Window which we then close after a specified time, it's child message box would close as well.

```
Window owner = CreateAutoCloseWindow(dialogTimeout);
MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(owner, ...
```

So far so good. But how do we close a window if the UI thread is blocked by the message box and UI controls can't be accessed from a worker thread? The answer is - by sending a WM_CLOSE windows message to the owner window handle:

```
Window CreateAutoCloseWindow(TimeSpan timeout)
{
    Window window = new Window()
    {
        WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None,
        WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized,
        Background =  System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Transparent, 
        AllowsTransparency = true,
        ShowInTaskbar = false,
        ShowActivated = true,
        Topmost = true
    };

    window.Show();

    IntPtr handle = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;

    Task.Delay((int)timeout.TotalMilliseconds).ContinueWith(
        t => NativeMethods.SendMessage(handle, 0x10 /*WM_CLOSE*/, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero));

    return window;
}
```

And here is the import for the SendMessage Windows API method:

```
static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
}
```

Comment: Window type is for Windows Forms ?

Comment: Why do you need to send a message to the hidden parent window to close it? Can't you just call some "Close" method on it or dispose it otherways?

Comment: To answer my own question, the OwnedWindows property of that WPF Window seems to show 0 windows and Close doesn't close the messagebox child

Comment: Briliant solution. There is some naming overlap in `System.Windows` and `System.Windows.Forms` that took me some time to figure out. You will need the following: `System`, `System.Runtime.InteropServices`, `System.Threading.Tasks`, `System.Windows`, `System.Windows.Interop`, `System.Windows.Media`

Answer (score 10):

[RogerB](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/View.aspx?mid=716667) over at CodeProject has one of the slickest solutions to this answer, and he did that back in '04, and it's still bangin'

Basically, you [go here to his project and download the CS file](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7968/MessageBox-with-a-timeout-for-NET). In case that link ever dies, I've got a backup [gist](https://gist.github.com/the-nose-knows/b933ab0a041cc482834c2184ccb27c3d) here. Add the CS file to your project, or copy/paste the code somewhere if you'd rather do that.

Then, all you'd have to do is switch

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Text","Title", MessageBoxButtons.CHOICE)
```

to

```
DialogResult result = MessageBoxEx.Show("Text","Title", MessageBoxButtons.CHOICE, timer_ms)
```

And you're good to go.

Comment: You missed the .Show extension in your examples... Should read: DialogResult result = MessageBoxEx.Show("Text","Title", MessageBoxButtons.CHOICE, timer_ms)

Answer (score 10):

I know this question is 8 year old, however there was and is a better solution for this purpose. It's always been there, and still is: **User32.dll!MessageBoxTimeout**.

This is an undocumented function used by Microsoft Windows, and it does exactly what you want and even more. It supports different languages as well.

C# Import:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int MessageBoxTimeout(IntPtr hWnd, String lpText, String lpCaption, uint uType, Int16 wLanguageId, Int32 dwMilliseconds);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
```

How to use it in C#:

```
uint uiFlags = /*MB_OK*/ 0x00000000 | /*MB_SETFOREGROUND*/  0x00010000 | /*MB_SYSTEMMODAL*/ 0x00001000 | /*MB_ICONEXCLAMATION*/ 0x00000030;

NativeFunctions.MessageBoxTimeout(NativeFunctions.GetForegroundWindow(), $"Kitty", $"Hello", uiFlags, 0, 5000);
```

Work smarter, not harder.

Comment: This solution worked for me immediately and within a single class. I removed the reference to _NativeFunctions_ since it was all kept local.

This seems easier than the other answers since I didn't need to download any other software and is dependable.

Answer (score 3):

A message box will be destroyed when its parent form is removed. We can use this to our advantage by creating a dummy form, showing the message box as a child of this form, and then closing the form when we no longer require the message box, after 30 seconds, for example.

This is how I did it:

```
var owner = new Form { TopMost = true };
Task.Delay(30000).ContinueWith(t => {
owner.Invoke(new Action(()=>
{
      if (!owner.IsDisposed)
      {
          owner.Close();
      }
   }));
});
var dialogRes =  MessageBox.Show(owner, msg, "Info", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by briefly explaining the basic approach to the code before showing it.

Answer (score 2):

[DMitryG's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522540/how-to-close-a-messagebox-after-several-seconds/14522952#14522952) to "get the return value of the underlying `MessageBox`" has a bug so the timerResult is never actually correctly returned (`MessageBox.Show` call returns AFTER `OnTimerElapsed` completes). My fix is below:

```
public class TimedMessageBox {
    System.Threading.Timer _timeoutTimer;
    string _caption;
    DialogResult _result;
    DialogResult _timerResult;
    bool timedOut = false;

    TimedMessageBox(string text, string caption, int timeout, MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.OK, DialogResult timerResult = DialogResult.None)
    {
        _caption = caption;
        _timeoutTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(OnTimerElapsed,
            null, timeout, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
        _timerResult = timerResult;
        using(_timeoutTimer)
            _result = MessageBox.Show(text, caption, buttons);
        if (timedOut) _result = _timerResult;
    }

    public static DialogResult Show(string text, string caption, int timeout, MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.OK, DialogResult timerResult = DialogResult.None) {
        return new TimedMessageBox(text, caption, timeout, buttons, timerResult)._result;
    }

    void OnTimerElapsed(object state) {
        IntPtr mbWnd = FindWindow("#32770", _caption); // lpClassName is #32770 for MessageBox
        if(mbWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
            SendMessage(mbWnd, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        _timeoutTimer.Dispose();
        timedOut = true;
    }

    const int WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a timer and start in when the MessageBox appears.
If your MessageBox only listens to the OK Button (only 1 possibility) then use the OnTick-Event to emulate an ESC-Press with `SendKeys.Send("{ESC}");` and then stop the timer.

---

There is also a codeproject project available [HERE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93429/messageBox-with-Timeout) that provides the functionality you ask for.

Comment: Timer concept is a simple way... but have to ensure the sent keys hit your app if it doesn't have or loses the focus. That would require SetForegroundWindow and the the answer starts to include more code, but see 'AppActivate' below.

Answer (score 1):

use `EndDialog` instead of sending `WM_CLOSE`:

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int EndDialog(IntPtr hDlg, IntPtr nResult);
```

Comment: This is the way to go if you have a message box with yes / no buttons

Answer (score 1):

Vb.net library has a simple solution using interaction class for this:

```
void MsgPopup(string text, string title, int secs = 3)
{
    dynamic intr = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
    intr.Popup(text, secs, title);
}

bool MsgPopupYesNo(string text, string title, int secs = 3)
{
    dynamic intr = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
    int answer = intr.Popup(text, secs, title, (int)Microsoft.VisualBasic.Constants.vbYesNo + (int)Microsoft.VisualBasic.Constants.vbQuestion);
    return (answer == 6);
}
```