# TimeOut in Java and C#

Tags: c#, java

If this is the way to get "timeout" of a system in Java:

```
timeoutMs = System.currentTimeMillis() + DataLog.getTimeout();
 try {
            dataLog.thread.join(DataLog.getTimeout());
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        if (!dataLog.thread.interrupted()) {
            dataLog.thread.interrupt();
        }
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > timeoutMs) {
            return ("Communication timeout");
        } else {
            return (dataLog.getResult());
        }
    }
```

Is the following code a good way to get the timeout of the system using C#?

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        timeoutMs=DataLog.getTimeout();
     }
```

It is a small part of a big Project so I do not have possibility to see the result in the output..please let me know If it is correct or not!

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Code provided doesn't makes sense. Your java code seems to compute a time in future, where as your c# code loops indefinitely calling a method.

Comment: Actually, The only thing that I want to do is converting that one line java code to C#

Comment: What does `getTimeout` method returns?

Comment: It returns:  
public static long getTimeout() {
    return Timeout.getDataLogTimeout();
  }

Comment: And `Timeout.getDataLogTimeout()` presumably returns `Settings.getDataLogTimeout()`.

Comment: In Timeout class there is a function which is called getDataLogTimeout()

Comment: @mk: you should describe **what** you are trying to accomplish. The code you have posted doesn't make sense. It's hard to suggest a way to do something, if you don't describe the purpose of the code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if this is your way of pausing a thread (e.g. to display a dialog for a certain amount of time), it's a very bad way to do it.

That being said, if you're using a `Stopwatch`, you could spin the CPU by simply doing this:

```
// start the stop 
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
while (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 1000)
{
     /* do nothing */ 
}
```

And, of course, you can do a nasty `Thread.Sleep` call to create a pause:

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

The closest to your code in C# would look something like:

```
var timeoutMs = Environment.TickCount + DataLog.Timeout;
```

But I am pretty sure that you are doing something terribly wrong.

Comment: @mk: For the updated question, this link should be more appropriate: [Close a MessageBox after several seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14522540/69809). There are many examples in that thread.

Comment: Thanks but I do not get their relevance! MessageBox and Timeout!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the current time in milliseconds and then add the timeout to it from your method, assuming a millseconds return value:

```
var x = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
var timeout = DataLog.getTimeOut();
var timeoutMs = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(x).Add(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeout))
```