# display wpf window on top of the messagebox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, telerik

Work Environment is in .Net with scripting language as c#(WPF)

[image: message box appears on top of the radwindow]

i'm unable to solve this issue.
my message box appears on top of the radwindow as you can see in the image.

please guide me, how can i make my radwindow appear on top of the message box.

What I'm trying to achieve?
I want to display a lock screen in application which will ask the user to enter the password if the user has been inactive for more than 5 minutes. For that I'm using telerik radwindow. For display the radwindow I'm using dispatchtimer. If the user has been inactive for over 5 minutes then I display the window(lock screen). The problem I'm facing is, on clicking the button I'm displaying a pop-up message which has a 'OK' button. When the message comes I leave my application idle for over 5 minutes and at that time my radwindow comes (i.e. displays) but it goes behind the pop-up message as you can see in the image which I attached. Please guide me how can I achieve this.

Comment: Isn't the messagebox supposed to do that? Being modal, on top of all other windows and centered? That is the default behavior. If you want something else, don't use a message box?

Comment: It would be better if you back up and explain what you are really trying to accomplish here, in plain English. Why did you decide to create the window? Why did you decide to show the message box? How does each help achieve the goal of your application?

Comment: @Ed Plunkett I have edited my OP, please check and guide me how can I achieve my goal.

Comment: @user1528468 1) I don't understand what the message box is for. 2) You write *"on clicking the button I'm displaying a pop-up message"*: What button? Are you talking about a button on the radwindow? What does it do? **Anyway:** Why do you NEED to have the message box? What purpose does it serve? Who launches it and why? BTW you can do a messagebox that closes itself after a timeout: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14522952/424129

Comment: @Ed Plunkett The button is a 'save' button on page. On clicking the button, I'm saving the data in database and display the message to the user, as 'do you want to save data'. The user needs to click either OK button or CANCEL button to close the message box. I can use the autoclose messagebox feature, but I need user confirmation to either click OK or cancel and because of that I can't use this feature.

Comment: If the user clicks Save and ignores the confirm prompt until the screen locks five minutes later, you can just cancel the save. Alternatively, a confirm prompt on Save is bad usability to begin with. Have you ever seen one in Word, Excel, or anything? Does Stack Overflow have one? No. Save means save. Is somebody forcibly imposing this requirement on you? If possible, just eliminate the Save confirmation box.

Comment: Another approach would be to write your own confirm dialog that you can explicitly move behind the other one when the need arises. But best by far is not to require the user to jump through redundant hoops. "Save". "You sure?" "Yes". "Are you REALLY sure?" "Yes". "Still sure?" "GGHHAGHGH!!"

Comment: The client's a fool, but it's his money. If you can't talk him out of it, you're stuck with either one of my workarounds above.