# how to pop up a message in c# that does not require user input to go away

Tags: c#, popup

I am trying to send the user confirmation of an action, without using MessageBox.Show() because it requires a button to be pressed to take the message off the screen.
I am copying some text for them into the Windows Clipboard, and want to notify them to save time.  But I'd rather not use MessageBox.Show().

Comment: So you´re building a status-bar into your app? This is just a bar within the app itself that does not pop up actually but simply a text within your window that show some status?

Comment: build / create a custom winform then

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close a MessageBox after several seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522540/close-a-messagebox-after-several-seconds)

Answer (score 2):

`MessageBox.Show()` simply displays a form with some buttons using `ShowDialog()` - You can create your own form, with a timer, and display it using the `ShowDialog()` method, start the timer on form load, and set the form's `DialogResult` property once the timer has ticked.
I would suggest to set the message as well as the time to display it in the form's constructor:

```
public TimedMessageBox(string message, int millisecondsToShow)
```

And in the main form:

```
var message = new TimedMessageBox("My message", 1000);
message.ShowDialog(this);
```

Don't forget to set the `TimedMessageBox` form `StartPosition` property to `CenterParent`.