# System.Windows.Messagebox Timeout Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, popup, timeout, messagebox

I need to ask about timeout with [System.Windows.MessageBox] the code is the next:

"logX" (like log1, log2 or log3) are function to write in a file, only change Log3. Log3 do "exit"(leave the Script) after write. We dont need the how work this function

```
#Funcion para comprobar si existe el token o no.
function Token{
#comprobamos si existe el fichero
$token = Test-Path $dir_token
if($token -eq $True){
    #Existe el fichero
    $ftoken = 1
}else{ 
    #No existe el fichero
    $ftoken = 0
}
return $ftoken
}

#Asignamos dirección de token
$Global:dir_token = "D:\Nuevacarpeta\Nueva carpeta\token.txt"
#Ejecutamos la funcion de Token para saber si existe ahora mismo
$ftoken = Token
#Preparamos la ruta del log
$log = "D:\Nuevacarpeta\log\log.txt"

#Creamos la variable Outlook transformandolo en un objeto (Commobject de Powershell)
$Global:outlook = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
$comprobaroutlook = Get-variable -name outlook
$valueoutlook = $comprobaroutlook.Value

if($valueoutlook.Equals("")){

$msgBoxInput =  [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Outlook no se puede tratar, SCRIPT FAIL, para Borrar token y continuar con la ejecución pulsa SI, para no borrar el token e ignorar este mensaje pulse NO','ERROR CRITICO SCRIPT','YesNo','Error')
switch  ($msgBoxInput) {
  'Yes' {
  ## Do something 
  Remove-Item -Path $dir_token
  [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("BORRADO TOKEN")
  Log3("Borrado token, proxima ejecución sera correcta")  
  }
  'No' {
  ## Do something
  [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("No hacemos nada, esperamos")
  Log3("No tiene contenido la variable outlook")
  }
}
}elseif($ftoken -eq 1){

$msgBoxIn = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Outlook no se puede tratar, SCRIPT FAIL, para Borrar token y continuar con la ejecución pulsa SI, para no borrar el token e ignorar este mensaje pulse NO','ERROR CRITICO SCRIPT','YesNo','Error')     
switch  ($msgBoxIn) {
  'Yes' {
  ## Do something 
  Remove-Item -Path $dir_token
  [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("BORRADO TOKEN")
  Log3("Borrado token, proxima ejecución sera correcta") 
  }
  'No' {
  ## Do something
  [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("No hacemos nada, esperamos")
  Log3("Existe Token")
  }
}

}else{

  New-Item -Path $dir_token -ItemType File

}
```

I ask about timeout in this lanes:

-[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("BORRADO TOKEN")
-[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("No hacemos nada, esperamos")

This message its only informative and i wanna show and close it 5 min after popup in the screen

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522540/close-a-messagebox-after-several-seconds

Comment: its C# i dont know C# or Visual Study. I am working with Powershell

Comment: You're using .NET assemblies which are the same for C# and Powershell

Comment: but the method and propiertys are diferent. The same method can be writed and do diferents results

Comment: The same method with the same input data will give the same result. .NET in C# is exactly the same as in Powershell, believe it or not.

Comment: I dont resolve my question, its only for C# dont work the same code in powershell

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `Wscript.Shell` COM object.

```
$sh = New-Object -ComObject "Wscript.Shell"
$intButton = $sh.Popup("Testing",2,"Title",0+64)
```

From [here](https://ss64.com/vb/popup.html):

> Syntax
>
> ```
>   intButton = objShell.Popup(strText,[nSecondsToWait],[strTitle],[nType])
> ```
>
> Arguments
>
> `objShell`       : A WScript.Shell object
>
> `strText`        : String value containing the text you want to
>   appear
>                       in the pop-up message box.
>
> `nSecondsToWait` : Maximum length of time to display the pop-up
>   message
>                       box (in seconds, Optional, default=infinite)
>
> `strTitle`       : Title text string, Optional.
>
> `nType`          : Type of buttons and icons (Numeric, Optional)
>                       These determine how the message box is used.
>
> `IntButton`      : Number of the button (Integer value) 
>                       This is the value returned when the user OK's the message box.
>
> The meaning of `nType` is determined by combining values from the 2
>   tables below:
>
> Button Types
>
> Value Description
>       0   OK button.
>       1   OK and Cancel buttons.
>       2   Abort, Retry, and Ignore buttons.
>       3   Yes, No, and Cancel buttons.
>       4   Yes and No buttons.
>       5   Retry and Cancel buttons.
>
> Icon Types
>          Value Description
>       16  "Stop Mark" icon.
>       32  "Question Mark" icon.
>       48  "Exclamation Mark" icon.
>       64  "Information Mark" icon.
>
> Possible values for `IntButton` the return value:
>
> Value Description
>       1  OK button
>       2  Cancel button
>       3  Abort button
>       4  Retry button
>       5  Ignore button
>       6  Yes button
>       7  No button
>
> If the user does not click a button before nSecondsToWait intButton is
>   set to -1.

Comment: Good, this can resolve the problem. I see I cant automat [System.Windows.MessageBox] dont work in Script with schedule task. Finally i need to do this command and remake the Script.
Thanks, +1

Comment: If this solves your problem, can you mark it as Answered?